# setting min and max date on suitelets form date picker

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a simple suitelet with a form where i have a date field.

```
let transcationDate = form.addField({
    id: 'transactiondate',
    label: 'Transaction date',
    type: sw.FieldType.DATE
});
```

Is there a simple way to set min and max date on the date picker ? I didn't find anything in the netsuite API, and I haven't had much luck with the client script. Basically I need to limit the date start and end date to current month start/end.

Worst case scenario I can check it on submit, but for better user experience it would be great to check it on input.

Any tips or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a ClientScript indeed and used the fieldChanged trigger to check for the date fork that you wish.

If you are working in a SuiteLet you can load the ClientScript using

```
form.clientScriptModulePath = 'SuiteScripts/nameOfYourCS.js';
```

Comment: attaching clientscript is not a problem, but any clue how i can limit the date picker to 'gray' out unavailable dates ?, or dose it have to work on fieldChange